# Bristol BRS airport free drop off/pick up?

Tags: public-transport, buses, automobiles, brs

I have friends in the Bristol (UK) area and use this airport to travel to them.

As I do not drive, most of the time one of them comes to the airport to pick me up after the flight or drop me off on the way home.
They always seem to have to pay for the 'pleasure' to come to the airport.

Traveling by bus instead does not seem to be a cheaper option, as you have to pay a premium to use the airport stop on the bus lines.

Is there a way to travel to and from the airport without having to pay a parking fee or a much more expensive bus ticket?

I am mostly not able to walk any distance with my luggage but at times I travel with only a small backpack and I can walk about 3 km / 2 mile or so, as long as it is safe walking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious bus to catch is the A1 'flyer'; as you've noticed this is expensive at £11 return or £7 one way (if you use the mticket app, otherwise add a pound). However, since the end of October there is now an A2 'airconnect'. This is just £4.50 one way, with no need to book (and thus no risk of misconnect). Services only run once every 30 minutes though, and will take longer than the A1 (which now uses Metrobus lanes to avoid traffic).

Less scrupulously, your driving friends could pick you up for free from the old terminal building / car rental offices about a five minute walk from the active terminal. Or you could hike a bit further out of the airport estate entirely; the Airport Tavern would be twelve minutes from arrivals and the route is suitable for pedestrians.

*Update Jan 2020*: there is now a free waiting zone by one of the car parks, accessible by passengers by a short (also free) bus ride from the terminal:

> Waiting Zone
>
> A free-of-charge space for taxis and public that are dropping off and collecting passengers.
>
> The Waiting Zone area is located close to the entrance of our Silver Zone car park and clearly sign posted upon entering the Silver Zone area.
>
> The Waiting Zone allows up to 1 hour free of charge that may be used for the waiting of passenger pick up, prior to collection from the Short Stay & Pick Up car park.
>
> There is access to a frequent bus service to the Terminal building if passengers do wish to be collected or dropped off in this area.
>
> The Waiting Zone has pedestrian signage to the bus stop location close by. From the terminal, passengers will be required to use bus stop 4 on the forecourt and board the bus for the Staff Transportation Hub.

Comment: Thanks, that is a helpful answer. And last time I was dropped off I had to walk from the car rentals anyhow, not sure whether my friend had to pay though.

Comment: Should be free; the OTB is still used by admin staff. But it's been a while since I worked there and I know they're constantly redeveloping.

Comment: There is continuous pavement all the way along North Side Road from the terminal building to the A38 roundabout, and if you turn north there, also right into Lulsgate village, where there are bus stops for local services, and the Airport Tavern, a prominent landmark. I go to and from Bristol Airport four to six times each year, and I often see pedestrians hauling wheely suitcases that way. You can see some on Google Street View, as well as what look like airport staff.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was wondering how far the Airport Tavern is; thanks for confirming it's a viable route for pedestrians, I've updated with that info.

Answer (score 2):

if you can book in advance, Megabus sells trips from Bristol Airport, outside the terminal, to central Bristol (Bond Street) from as little as £5.00.

[Megabus](https://uk.megabus.com/journey-planner/journeys?days=1&concessionCount=0&departureDate=2018-12-18&destinationId=13&inboundOtherDisabilityCount=0&inboundPcaCount=0&inboundWheelchairSeated=0&nusCount=0&originId=249&otherDisabilityCount=0&pcaCount=0&totalPassengers=1&wheelchairSeated=0)

Comment: Arriving, with usual delays and hold-ups in arrivals and immigration, I do not think advance booking will work well, but I will have a look.